# Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface

Tags: magento2.3, error, setup-di-compile, compiler

During compiling I've got the following compilation error:

Incompatible argument type: 
        Required type: `\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface.`
        Actual type: `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;`

Any ideas what is wrong and how this can be corrected?

```
   <?php

namespace Support\Cart2QuotePdf\Model\Quote\Pdf;

/**
 * Quote PDF model
 */
class Quote extends \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Quote
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer|\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer
     */
    protected $_addressRenderer;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
     */
    protected $localeResolver;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $quotes;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate
     */
    protected $translate;

    /**
     * Quote constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate $translate
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param Items\QuoteItem $renderer
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Translate $translate,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Items\QuoteItem $renderer,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->translate = $translate;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver;
        $this->_addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
        parent::__construct(
            $translate,
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $storeManager,
            $localeResolver,
            $renderer,
            $fileFactory,
            $data
        );
    }
```

di.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Quote" type="Support\Cart2QuotePdf\Model\Quote\Pdf\Quote" />
    <preference for="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Items\QuoteItem" type="Support\Cart2QuotePdf\Model\Quote\Pdf\Items\QuoteItem" />
</config>
```

`Cart2Quote/Quotation/Model/Quote/Pdf/Quote.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2019. Cart2Quote B.V. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf;

/**
 * Quote PDF model
 */
class Quote extends \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\AbstractPdf
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer|\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer
     */
    protected $_addressRenderer;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
     */
    protected $localeResolver;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $quotes;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate
     */
    protected $translate;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quotationFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * System event manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * Quote constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate $translate
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param Items\QuoteItem $renderer
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     * @param \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\QuoteFactory $quotationFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param array $data
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Translate $translate,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Items\QuoteItem $renderer,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\QuoteFactory $quotationFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->translate = $translate;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver;
        $this->_addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->quotationFactory = $quotationFactory;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;

        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $renderer,
            $data
        );
    }
```

Comment: Have you added **preference** for any class in di.xml ?

Comment: Hi @Aji I've updated the question with the contents of di.xml

Comment: share the code `\Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Quote`?

Comment: Hi Amit. It's updated on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<preference for="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Quote" type="Support\Cart2QuotePdf\Model\Quote\Pdf\Quote" />
```

For this preference added in di.xml, Please use the below code and check whether you can get rid of the error.

```
<?php

namespace Support\Cart2QuotePdf\Model\Quote\Pdf;

use Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Quote as CartQuote

class Quote extends CartQuote
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer|\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer
     */
    protected $_addressRenderer;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
     */
    protected $localeResolver;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $quotes;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate
     */
    protected $translate;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quotationFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * System event manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * Quote constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate $translate
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Items\QuoteItem $renderer
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     * @param \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\QuoteFactory $quotationFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param array $data
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Translate $translate,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\Quote\Pdf\Items\QuoteItem $renderer,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Cart2Quote\Quotation\Model\QuoteFactory $quotationFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {

    parent::__construct(
        $translate,
        $paymentData,
        $string,
        $scopeConfig,
        $filesystem,
        $pdfConfig,
        $pdfTotalFactory,
        $pdfItemsFactory,
        $localeDate,
        $inlineTranslation,
        $addressRenderer,
        $storeManager,
        $localeResolver,
        $renderer,
        $addressRepository,
        $fileFactory,
        $customerSession,
        $quoteFactory,
        $quotationFactory,
        $customerRepositoryInterface,
        $eventManager,
        $data
    );
    }

}
```

**Make sure you run setup:di:compile command**

Comment: Hi @Aji; after implementing your changes; it now says: Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Translate. Actual type: \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data;

Comment: Hi @JulianMurillo, I have updated the parent::__construct() argument list in my answer. Please use my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Aji It works; thank u :)